# Check for NaN in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, nan, clojurescript

How can I check if a value is `NaN`?  I'd prefer a solution that can be used in Clojure too without much extra stuff (so I don't want to use an external library, such as underscore).  Here is what I tried

```
(number? js/NaN) ;=> true, well I'd expect false
(= js/NaN (js/parseInt "xx")) ;=> false
(= js/NaN js/NaN) ;=> false, even worse

; This is the best I could come up with
(defn actual-number? 
  [n] 
  (or (> 0 n) (<= 0 n)))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You shouldn't compare NaN's - they're always unequal. You should be able to use javascript's built-in isNaN function like

```
(js/isNaN x)
```

Comment: Note that the `js/isNaN` function doesn't exist in IE11. I've just hit this problem!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isNaN` js function:

`(js/isNaN ..)`

Comment: Beware: `js/isNaN` doesn't exist in IE11.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that

`(js/isNaN [1,2])`

returns true. There are other many cases where js/isNaN does not correspond to what one expects.

If you're using underscore.js in the browser, you can delegate to (.isNaN js/_ ..) instead.

Otherwise, the following function should to the trick:

```
(defn isNaN [node]
  (and (= (.call js/toString node) (str "[object Number]"))
       (js/eval (str node " != +" node ))))
```